# Biopython HSExposure Module 'NotImplemented' Error

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to calculate HSExposure values by using Biopython lib(1.63), however, it returns an error somthing like 'NotImplemented object is not iterable'. When I checked out the module I found out one of the function in HSExposure module is like following:

```
def _get_cb(self, r1, r2, r3): 
    """This method is provided by the subclasses to calculate HSE.""" 
    return NotImplemented
```

What is wrong with that you guys think?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The method is not implemented, so you get the exception by intention.

And in python all method names, that start with an "_" (underscore) are only for internal use, by convention. So you are not meant to call it, it is only made for calls by this library itself.

(I am not familiar with that library and can not offer an alternative).